# Sorting a ListView Adapter for an item that isn't in the Adapter

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview, adapter

I'm doing an app that uses BaseAdapter to see installed app in an Android device.
In this Listview there are more items, but in the adapter there are only two, and from the second (the package name) I get the other ones

I'm searching a way to sort the items of this adapter for an item that is in the listview, but not in the adapter. Here there is my code:

```
class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context mContext;
private List<Pair<String, List<String>>> mAppsWithPermission;


AppsAdapter(Context context, List<Pair<String, List<String>>> appsWithPermission) {
    mContext = context;
    mAppsWithPermission = appsWithPermission;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView appName;
    TextView appPermissions;
    ImageView appIcon;
    TextView Lines;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mAppsWithPermission.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mAppsWithPermission.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mAppsWithPermission.get(position).hashCode();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.appName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_appname);
        holder.appPermissions = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_apppermissions);
        holder.appIcon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_appicon);
        holder.Lines = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_lines);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Pair<String, List<String>> item = mAppsWithPermission.get(position);

    final PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    String mAppPer = item.second.toString();

    int lineCount = holder.appPermissions.getLineCount();
    Log.v("LINE_NUMBERS", lineCount+"");

    String strI = Integer.toString(lineCount);
    holder.Lines.setText(strI);

    if (mAppPer.matches("")) {
    holder.Lines.setText("0");
    }

    });
return convertView;
}
}
```

When you see "item.second" it's the package name.

As you can think, I'm trying to sort the entire adapter for the descendant value of holder.lines (so StrI).

This is a different question from the others that talks about sorting an adapter, because I want to sort the adapter for an external value.
If you need further informations, you've just to ask me.

Comment: I think you should 1) Replace `Pair<String, List<String>>` with an actual class 2) Make that class `implements Comparable` or define a `Comparator` that's able to sort your data... Alternatively, you must sort the data before sticking it into `new AppsAdapter`

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 thank you for the help, but can you help me with the coding of a Comparator? I've already tried to do one, without success… Where have I to put it into? What should I write? Thank you for the help

Comment: Do not add "not solved" or "solved" to the title of the question.

Comment: @Zoe ok, I'll keep it in mind